# Spring Cloud stream: Kafka Sink gets alternate message

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build a simple cloud stream application with kafka binding. Let me describe the set up.
1. I have a producer producing to topic `topic_1`. 
2. There's a stream binder, binding `topic_1` after some processing into `topic_2`.

```java
@StreamListener(MyBinder.INPUT)
    @SendTo(MyBinder.OUTPUT_2)
    public String handleIncomingMsgs(String s) {
        logger.info(s);  // prints all the messages
        return s;
    }
```

3. When the producer produces messages, the `StreamListner handleIncomingMsgs` gets all the messages.
4. After receiving, it should forward the messages to some other channel.

```java
@Service
@EnableBinding(MyBinder.class)
public class LogMsg {

    @StreamListener(MyBinder.OUTPUT_2)
    public void handle(String board) {
        logger.info("Received payload: " + board); //prints every alternate messages
    }
```

5. Here is my binder

```java
public interface ViewsStreams {

    String INPUT = "input";
    String OUTPUT_1 = "output_1";
    String OP_USERS = "output_2";

    @Autowired
    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel job_board_views();

    @Autowired
    @Output(OUTPUT_1)
    MessageChannel outboundJobBoards();

    @Autowired
    @Output(OUTPUT_2)
    MessageChannel outboundUsers();
}
```

I am new in these technologies. Unable to figure out what is going wrong here. Can someone please help?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: ```LogMsg``` gets every alternate message. Other messages are dropped. I think I am getting what is wrong here. Doing last bit of testing, will update soon. Can ```StreamListener``` listen to a ```Processor.OUTPUT```? I think no. It is a ```MessageChannel``` and meant to send the message out of application. We need a conumer to receive the message send to a ```MessageChannel```.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct; you have two consumers on the OUTPUT_2 channel - the listener and the binding which sends out the message.

They each get alternate messages.

Comment: Thank you for validating. I fixed it.
now I have to consumers like this ```@KafkaListener(topics = "output_2", groupId = "foo")``` and the binder outputs sends messages into those.